# C# date based loop

Tags: c#, date, for-loop

I am writing an application in c# that needs to execute a code every two or three months etc. based on what month the item was added. For example if the month was February it would be represented as an int with the value 2. Therefore, it needs to run on  april(4), june(6) etc. I don't really know how to do this, any help would be really great

heres what i have so far

```
 // month is febuary
string month = monthAsInt(date);
for(int w= month; month <= 12; w++)
{
 w++;
  //thats not going to work if month is greater than 0
  if(?)
  {
   //execute
  }
}
```

Comment: You should better create a timer and set the intervals accordingly. Using a for loop is a giant waste of processing power.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `w` twice?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear enough for anyone to actually give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wuld suggest do not invent your functions for acting with [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (as there are a lot of non trivial stuff out there), but simply relay to .NET library functions like:

[DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So first construct your "start" `DateTime` object, after use these functions to shift date to desired edge.

Comment: would this be on the right trackstartDate  = startDate.AddMonths(interval);

Comment: if interval is amount of months o need to shift to from the given date, yes.

Comment: thanks got it too work both solutions were great thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution is to store `DateTime` object somewhere (for example, serialize and deserialize it in a file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) and compare it with current every time the application loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
int monthJump = 2;
int month = monthAsInt(date);
for(int w= month; w <= 12; w = w + monthJump){
    //Execute
}
```

So for this, you say that it need to work every 2 or 3 months. You simply set that value in the `monthJump` variable and it does the jumps for you in the `FOR` loop

I am assuming, based on the method name that this

```
string month = monthAsInt(date);
```

should be

```
int month = monthAsInt(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may probably be usefull. Just verify month difference is multiple of 2:

```
 DateTime dateAdded; // Your date
 DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

 int dateAddedMonth = dateAdded.Month;
 int currentDateMonth = currentDate.Month;

 int difference = dateAddedMonth - currentDateMonth;
 if (difference % 2 == 0)
 {
    // Do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: This solution is far too inflexible. I don't think it's a great idea to assume the interval will always be an even number of months.

Comment: Just replace the "2" in the "if" clause to make it cyclic each 3, 4, 5,.. months. Wouldn't it make it?

Comment: The point I was making was this isn't the rule - the rule is "run the code after X interval from current date" not "run code if the month is divisible by X". You could of course implement it this way if you made `% 2` variable, however, for me you lose readability.

Comment: OK, just got your purpouse. You are right making %2 vaiable would solve it, although losing readability. Please post the final code to see how you did it :-)